# Как сделать что бы бот реагировал только на 1 команду в секунду?

Tags: aiogram

Нужно что бы бот реагировал только на 1 команду в секунду а если отправится 2 команды одну из них он проигнорирует. Возможно ли такое? Использую aiogram

Answer (score 0):

если только через asyncio.sleep(time)